# Is it possible to add third audio track which is mixed from previous two in FFMPEG in one line?

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, alsa, pulseaudio

I have this command:

```bash
ffmpeg -y -f x11grab -s 1920x1080 -framerate 12 -i :0+0,0 -f pulse -i 2394 -f alsa -i default -map 0 -ac 2 -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset fast -crf 40 -b:v 1000K -bufsize 8K -c:a libopus -b:v 1K -map 1:a -map 2:a test.mkv
```

Which outputs following streams

```
Output #0, matroska, to 'test.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), bgr0(progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 1 kb/s, 12 fps, 1k tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 hevc_nvenc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/1000 buffer size: 8000 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: opus ([255][255][255][255] / 0xFFFFFFFF), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libopus
  Stream #0:2: Audio: opus ([255][255][255][255] / 0xFFFFFFFF), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 96 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libopus
```

Is it possible to add `-filter_complex amix=inputs=2` somewhere and create and map a new audio stream to an output file?

I already have audio inputs `#0:1` and `#0:2` that are mapped separately to the output.

How do I mix them together and add a new `#0:3` stream without compromising the first two?

Also this has to be in one command cause this runs from a script that creates file by date and time.